# oracle triggers :new context variable

Tags: oracle

### Question:

A Trigger which automatically stores in a separate table called ‘ExcellentSale’ the Sales Agent
name, car model and manufacturer name, each time the agreed price of a
SalesTransaction is more than 20% of the car’s asking price. (Note: You need to create
the ‘ExcellentSale’ table before implementing this trigger. To create the primary key, use a
sequence that starts at 1 and increments by 1).

I am using these tables

```
Manufacturer(manufacturerID, name, region)

Model(modelNo, name, type, previousModel, manufacturerID)

Car(VIN, dateAcquired, yearBuilt, purchasedPrice, askingPrice,
currentMileage, modelNo)

SalesAgent(agentID, name, DOB)

SalesTransaction(VIN, custID, agentID, dateOfSale, agreedPrice)
```

Here is my attempt

```
create sequence generateKey
start with 1
increment by 1;
CREATE TABLE ExcellentSale(
recordNo NUMBER,
agentName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
modelName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
manufacturerName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(recordNo));
create or replace trigger AutoStore
before insert on SalesTransaction
for each row
declare
SAname varchar2(50);
carModel varchar2(50);
manufacturerName varchar2(50);
askingprice number;
agreedprice number;
begin
select sa.name, mo.name, mu.name, c.askingprice, st.agreedprice
into SAname, CarModel, manufacturerName, askingprice, agreedprice
from manufacturer MU, Model MO, Car C, SalesAgent SA, SalesTransaction ST
where mu.manufacturerid = mo.manufacturerid
and st.vin = c.vin
AND c.vin = :new.vin
AND sa.agentID = :new.agentID;
IF :new.agreedPrice > (1.2 * askingPrice) THEN 
INSERT INTO ExcellentSale
VALUES
(generateKey.nextval, agentName, modelName, manufacturerName);
END IF; 
end AutoStore;
/
```

and the error I am getting is

> PL/SQL: ORA -00984: Column not allowed here

please help, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Once you've fixed that, you're missing some join conditions, e.g. between C and MO. It would be more obvious those were missing if you used ANSI join syntax, rather than the old implicit joins.

Answer (score 1):

In the VALUES clause of the insert statement, you have go use the variables that hold the values you need instead of the column names.

```
INSERT INTO ExcellentSale
VALUES
(generateKey.nextval, SAname, CarModel, manufacturerName);
```